# React-Native: connectionChange event strange behavior with Android

Tags: android, react-native, types

The connectionChange event is not triggered after the first launch, I have to change a file to trigger a build to have the "Connection type" log displayed.
It works great with IOS, only have the issue with Android.
Is there anything wrong in my code?

```
import { ConnectionInfo, NetInfo } from "react-native"
import { Observable, Observer } from "rxjs"
import { publishReplay, refCount, tap } from "rxjs/operators"

export const connectivityStatus$: Observable<ConnectionInfo> = Observable.create((observer: Observer<ConnectionInfo>) => {
  const handler = observer.next.bind(observer)
  console.log("entering connection:")
  NetInfo.addEventListener("connectionChange", handler)
  console.log("entering connection 2:")
  return () => NetInfo.removeEventListener("connectionChange", handler)
}).pipe(
  tap((s: ConnectionInfo) => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
      console.log("Connection type:", s.type)
    }
  }),
  publishReplay(),
  refCount(),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NetInfo to track connectivity changes then you must put in these 2 lines on the top of your android manifest file (inside the manifest tag)

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: I have those 2 lines in the Android manifest. It is working after a rebuild of the app (if I change and save a file). It does not get the "connectionChange" during the initial launch.